# Precedence of local variable over Property?

Tags: parameters, properties, vb6

I am working on a bit of VB6 which has some code in a class defintion  that boils down to this:-

```
Private intMyValue as Integer

Public Property Get MyValue as Integer
    MyValue = intMyValue
End Property

Public Sub DoFoo (ByVal MyValue As Integer)
    Dim bar As Integer
    bar = MyValue
End Sub
```

The question is: in the assignment to `bar`, is the Property used or the Parameter?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, in my current test case they're both zero.

Comment: Now I have woken up and run the test with some bodge-up assignments on the sly, I can say that it is the passed parameter version of MyValue that is used, not the property.

Comment: One of the reasons that VB6, among other languages, often uses variable prefixes as a naming convention.  `Private m_intMyValue` or more commonly `miMyValue` or `m_iMyValue`(i being short for Integer).  And then for a parameter just `iMyValue`, differentiating them from property names..

Comment: @tcarvin, and so it is, theoretically, in the product I am currently working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check is to see what the IDE thinks will be used.

Here's an example:

```
Property Get test() As Integer
    test = 1
End Property

Private Sub test2(test As Integer)
    Debug.Print test 'Place cursor here
End Sub
```

If you place the cursor on the `test` in the line indicated and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> (or right-click and select *Definition*) it highlights the `test` in `test As Integer` (the parameter).

As a double-check, if you rename the parameter to something else and do this again, then it highlights the property called `test`.

I assume this is consistent with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

By stepping through the code and assigning a known value to intMyValue in the debug environment, I determined the Parameter and not the Property is the one used.

I can't see any way of deducing that from first principles, though. Or the closest VB6 gets to first principles, anyway.

Comment: Isn't this just standard scoping rules? Procedure scope overrides module scope (and global too for that matter), and procedure scope includes its parameters.

Comment: As Jim Mack says, you can get there via first principles via the scoping rules.  Something else to consider is how funky the rest of the code is.  Are variables declared as strings and then used as ints? Does the code have if/else blocks that are nigh identical? Over use of on resume next? If the code looks good general, you should start with the assumption that it does the right thing.